# how to find the length of the file in python3?

Tags: python, text-files, content-length

My first.py:

```
def create_file(file_name):
list=["ab","cd","ef"]
for i in list:
    with open(file_name, "a+") as input_file:
        print(" {}".format(i), file = input_file)
```

My second.py:

```
from first import create_file
def read_file(file_name):
# Create file with content
create_file(file_name)

# Now read file content
input_file = open(file_name, 'r')
for text_line in input_file:     
   for line in range(len(input_file)):
      if "cd" in text_line :
         word = (input_file[line + 1])
         print(word)


 read_file('ss.txt')
```

I am unable to find the length of the `input_file`.

I do not know why. Can somebody please help me?

Expected Output:

> ef

Then if line num =2 I want the output as "ef".

Comment: Length or size?

Comment: length of the ss.txt file

Comment: Example: 0 ab 1 cd 2 ef

Comment: You're then looking for number of lines. see the edit in my answer below

Comment: Your example given is vague. Please elaborate.

Comment: if the length of the line is "2"  i want to print "ef" as output

Comment: A simple condition would do it, do you want to print differently for each line? I mean there could millions of lines in file.

Comment: see the Edit 2 in my answer?

Comment: You have twisted the question pretty badly. Please post a sample of what is inside your `input_file` Now that you've posted the expected output of it.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon the same question while doing a mini project.The below code worked for me:

```
with open("filename","r") as f:
    print(len(f.readlines()))  # This would give length of files.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for. It iterates over the file line by line.

```py
input_file = open(file_name, 'r')     
for line in input_file.readlines():
    print(line)
```

If you want the number of lines in the file, do the following.

```
lines_in_file = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
number_of_lines = len(lines_in_file)
```

[Here's](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) a basic tutorial on file operations for further reading.

Comment: correct but i want that text line along with the line number

Comment: how to find a particular word and print next line please help me

Comment: You could use regular expressions to find a specific word in a line, https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, but this question is different from your initial one. Create a new question if you want answer to multiple questions.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without iterating over each line or by loading the entire file into memory (as in this post)?

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions that I have seen load everything into memory which I do not have the luxury of doing when I got to this post.
So you could create a manual counter for each line read.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as read_obj:
reader = reader(read_obj)
counter = 0
for row in reader:
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Hi, the indentation of your code isn't correct? Also please add where you're importing `reader` from.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that's memory efficient because you have a very large file, it's actually quite simple:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as filehandle:
    counter = 0
    for line in filehandle:
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```